# not clause in neo4j as recommendation engine

Tags: database, graph, neo4j, cypher

I am able to create relationship between material and the enduser who bought it using below code

```
match (n:demodb)
merge (f:material {id:n.material})
merge (t:enduser {id:n.endUser})
create (f)-[r:BOUGHT]->(t) return f,t limit 100;
```

but now I want to find materials not bought by enduser and show as recommendation engine in graph. I am new to cypher and Neo4J . please suggest

I tried using Not clause but its not working or may be I am missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try NOT predicate as such:

```
MATCH(f:material),(t:enduser) WHERE NOT (f)-[:BOUGHT]->(t) return f,t
```